# difference between conformal map, biholomorphic map and automorphism

Tags: complex-analysis

Could anyone tell me what the difference is between a map which is conformal, bi-holomorphic and an automorphism from $D\rightarrow D$ or $D$ to the upper half plane (in that case I know that is not automorphism)?

Maybe I am getting confused about terminology? Please someone explain with examples.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A conformal map is a holomorphic map whose derivative does not vanish. So it must be locally injective, but not necessarily surjective or injective.

A biholomorphism is a map which is bijective and holomorphic (then its inverse is also holomorphic). An automorphism is a biholomorphism $U \rightarrow U$ where $U$ is a complex domain (or a Riemann surface). In your example they are the same thing.

Example of a conformal map which is not injective : 
$z \mapsto e^z$. Its derivative does not vanish but it is not injective (and not surjective since its range doesn't contain $0$).

About the automorphism of the unit disk : it can be shown that they are exactly the :
$B_\alpha(z)=\frac{\alpha -z}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}$, where $|\alpha|<1$.

Comment: so a biholomorphism need not be conformal right?

Comment: actually it does. this is a special property of holomorphic functions, wich says that if the derivative vanishes at a point $z_0$ then $f$ cannot be locally injective near $z_0$ (this is of course false in general if $f$ is not holomorphic)